# Duda con el Toast en un lector de código QR

Tags: android, qrcode

He creado un lector de codigo QR que funciona con zxing.

Al escanear el código, el resultado se envía a un toast.

Quiero que el mensaje que resulte del código QR se muestre en otra ventana y si es un enlace que me permita abrirlo con el navegador predeterminado de mi teléfono móvil.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void scan(View view){
        zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente que es lo que no sabes? ¿Abrir otra actividad?, ¿Comprobar si es una url?

Comment: si, exactamente eso. soy nuevo en android.

Comment: Prácticamente pides un tutorial, y el sitio esta para resolver dudas. Podría recomendarte buscar en google "crear activity android studio", leer y aprender como funciona. Sobre el asunto de comprobar si es una url, has de tener en cuenta que el código qr puede contener no solo texto o una url, también una combinación de ambos, has de tener eso en cuenta a la hora de realizar la acción. En tu pregunta anterior te dejaron un buen ejemplo sobre como convertir el String a url, el resto de comprobaciones que comento se hacen de manera sencilla en java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        @Override
            public void handleResult(Result result) {
//Verifica el URL
                    if(isUrl(result.getText())){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(result.getText());
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            startActivity(intent);
    }else{
    //Muestra es el texto cuando no es un URL
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
                zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

            }
    private static boolean isUrl(String s) {
        String regex = "^(https?://)?(([\\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+: )?[\\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([\\w!~*'()-]+\\.)*([\\w^-][\\w-]{0,61})?[\\w]\\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/*)|(/+[\\w!~*'().;?:@&=+$,%#-]+)+/*)$";

        try {
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
            return matcher.matches();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: La expresión regular no coincide con todas las URLs válidas. Hay excepciones (raras, pero las hay). Realmente es mucho más sencillo y efectivo ver si coincide con `"(?i)^https?://"`